# Failed to save modifications to the server in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Can someone help me with the error: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The following system error occurred: Class not registered
'.
I am getting this while loading the excel/csv. I tried uninstalling the application quite many times but no luck, I still see the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share the source from where you downloaded the Power BI?

If you have downloaded from Microsoft windows store, try uninstalling it and then reinstall Power BI with installer instead of Microsoft Store version from the official website.

Download the version of Power BI Desktop that matches the architecture (x86 or x64) of your Windows OS. Run the MSI installer and follow the setup steps.

Microsoft Power BI Desktop is available for 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (x64) platforms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be server to desktop version mismatch. Are you using power-BI report server or cloud service? What is the version of your desktop power-BI?
Are you using any custom connector?
It seems to me the compatibility issue.

The last thing I would request you to check is the size of the file you are trying to publish.

Comment: I am unable to import excel or csv. I am using Power BI desktop version. And even after uninstalling and then installing again, I keep getting this error: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The following system error occurred: Class not registered 
 '. I am not using any connector. just a basic import of an excel or csv. Also installing the application from App store

Comment: This is the version that I am using: Version: 2.84.701.0 64-bit (August 2020)

Comment: and Power-BI server? Is that Power-BI report server or online?